# Override a CSS style on one page

Tags: html, xhtml, css, netsuite

I have a page (http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk/newhomepage)

I want to make the center column (#content-column) 930px for this page only, which will eventually become the homepage.

The CMS used is [NetSuite](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/products/ecommerce/website-hosting.shtml), and is notoriously difficult to work with.

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible with just CSS/HTML commands or JavaScript?

Comment: why on earth would anyone use a CMS that is 'notoriously difficult to work with'?

Comment: Can you add an id or classes to the body tag based on what page it is?

Comment: Because I have no choice! lol. The majority of the deeper sections of the site are locked down, almost completely. So adding of id's or classes is pretty much impossible in certain levels.

Comment: Netsuite isn't a CMS it is a SAAS CRM/Web store/Accounting/etc. that happens to allow you to serve static pages. Is the content you want to style in the web store or in the hosted pages?

Comment: @Craig see [this](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/products/ecommerce/website-hosting.shtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a CMS you probably cannot add markup easily so I'm thinking some jQuery would be a simple solution here...

```
$(function () {
    var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
    if (path) {
        var regex = new RegExp('newhomepage$', 'gi');
        if (regex.test(path)) $('#content-column').addClass('yourClass');
    }
});
```

This *should* add "yourClass" to the element *just* on that page.

Then you can add to your external CSS...

```
.yourClass {
    width: 930px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it does look like jquery/javascript is going to be the only way!

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain

I have used Netsuite extensively and found )after many hours of hair pulling and expletives) that the best solution (for us) has been to create the home page and any unique landing pages as Hard coded Hosted pages (hosted on Netsuite) and reserve Netsuite's CMS system for  item pages where you need the add to cart functionality.

Take it from me in the long run it'll save you hours of frustration :-)

Of course you can use Netsuite tags all over the place as long as you host the pages in your "site" folder

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Netsuite so please take this as is..

I would try to add a custom style tag to the document like this:

```
<style>
    #content-column{
        width:930px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work since NetSuite uses !important on nearly everything.

Comment: @John You can scope the CSS higher, something like the following:

`html #content-column {
    width: 930px !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you only have access to the HTML of that page, then put an inline style attribute in the center column's HTML.  Example:

```
<div id="content-column" style="width: 930px;">
```